# BreezeController returns wrong object created dynamically?

Tags: breeze

This is my code:

```
[Authorize]
[BreezeController]
public class BreezeController : ApiController
{
    private readonly MyRepository _repository;

    public BreezeController()
    {
        _repository = new MyRepository(User);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<Compound> Compounds(int id)
    {
        var compounds = new List<Compound>();
        compounds.add(new Compound() { Name = "cmp1" });
        compounds.add(new Compound() { Name = "cmp2" });
        compounds.add(new Compound() { Name = "cmp3" });
        return compounds.AsQueryable();
    }
}
```

On the client side, I do get three compounds returned, however, all three have the same content as the last one (cmp3). Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined a unique Id somewhere for your Compound model.  If you have a constructor you need to make sure you are generating an Id for those objects, or manually assign them.

When the server passes the objects back down to Breeze client-side your entity manager doesn't know that it is supposed to generate Ids unless you tell it to.  When it materializes those entities from the query they all have the same Id (null, probably) which is unique.  Breeze is most likely thinking you are passing three instances of the same object.

Either assign the entities an Id on the server before you pass them back or consider creating them client side.

Comment: That was exactly the problem. Thank you very much! I have to create those objects on server because they are created with help of other libraries. Ideally, I'd like to be able to save them to database right away, but I couldn't figure out how. Please see my other question at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22432592/angular-breeze-how-to-save-the-data-in-breezecontroller-to-database-directly) .