# Angular/Breeze: how to save the data in BreezeController to database directly

Tags: entity-framework, breeze

This is my breezeController using EF repository:

```
[BreezeController]
public class BreezeController : ApiController
{
    private readonly MyRepository _repository;

    public BreezeController()
    {
        _repository = new MyRepository(User);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateHttpAntiForgeryToken]
    public SaveResult SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle)
    {
        return _repository.SaveChanges(saveBundle);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<Compound> Compounds(int id)
    {
        var compounds = new List<Compound>();
        compounds.add(new Compound() { Name = "cmp1" });
        compounds.add(new Compound() { Name = "cmp2" });
        compounds.add(new Compound() { Name = "cmp3" });

        // Save compounds to database

        return compounds.AsQueryable();
    }
}
```

I'd like to save the compounds created here to database before returning. Should I call SaveChanges? How?

UPDATE: 
I tried to bring the objects to client and save. However, I can't seem to use those objects directly as:

```
cs.compound = compound;
manager.saveChanges();
```

Because I'm getting this error "Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries". How can I get around this error? I believe I just missed a little tweak.

Instead, I had to create entity as usual, and assign properties one by one like

```
cs.compound = manager.createEntity("Compound");
cs.compound.name = compound.name;
...
manager.saveChanges();
```

This is quite cumbersome because I have a lot of properties and nested objects.

So, how can I use the objects created on server to save directly?

Comment: Are you saying that for each query issued on `Compounds` , the list should be added to the database? What's the point here? Where is the use of `id` parameter?

Comment: This is just some sample code to illustrate the problem. In real life, compounds are detected based on the id passed in with help of other libraries.

Comment: @miliu your question doesn't make any sense - the Breeze saveChanges method is on the entity manager client-side.  Why not just create a new entity on the server and return it to the client?  If you are using EF this should be really simple...

Comment: I'm thinking of using the method shown above public SaveResult SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle); So, how do I create the saveBundle for those new objects?

Comment: @PWKad I updated my question with a new problem I face. Hope you can give me some tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have an idea of how you declared the dbContext inside the repository.
Let's say you have it declared this way :

```
public MyDBContext { get { return _contextProvider.Context; } }
```

Then you can add the `_repository.MyDBContext.SaveChanges();`
right before the line

```
return compounds.AsQueryable();
```

Comment: This is great. It saves me a lot of headaches. Thank you very much!